# How to grab a CSS syntax with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi guys I have a fadeIn fadeOut transition in CSS. I want to create a variable for `animation-duration` but I don't know how to grab the whole CSS id and class where I set this. Please have a look over this and let me know if this is possible.

This is my CSS where animation-duration is 8s.

```
#banner img.top {
  animation-name: bannerFadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

And something like this I want to make in JavaScript

```
var duration = 4s;
document.getElementById("banner or whatever needs to be here").style.animationDuration = duration;
```

Comment: What you have is fine, you're just missing quotes around `4s` - should be `"4s"` since it's a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var duration = '4s';

document.getElementById("yourID").style.webkitAnimationDuration = duration;
// or
document.getElementById("yourID").style.animationDuration = duration;
```

Comment: What I need to know is what should I put in "yourID" as in my CSS is #banner img.top where #banner is ID img is Tag and .top is Class

Comment: The input is the id of the target element without the hashtag. So in your example: document.getElementById("banner"). Note that this only works for an id-selector!